# How to display angle found from 3 3d points using opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv, math, mediapipe

I have the following code to calculate angle between 3 body points for my opencv project and display them:

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import numpy as np
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_pose = mp.solutions.pose


def Calc_Angle(a, b, c):
    pointA = np.array(a)
    pointB = np.array(b)
    pointC = np.array(c)

    BA = pointA - pointB
    BC = pointC - pointB

    angle = np.degrees(np.arccos(np.dot((BA,BC) / (np.linalg.norm(BC) * np.linalg.norm(BC)))))
    return angle




cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
#set up mediapipe instance
with mp_pose.Pose(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as pose:
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        
        # Recolor image to RGB
        image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image.flags.writeable = False
      
        # Make detection
        results = pose.process(image)
    
        # Recolor back to BGR
        image.flags.writeable = True
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        
        # Extract landmarks
        try:
            landmarks = results.pose_landmarks.landmark
            
            # Get coordinates
            shoulder = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER.value].x,landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER.value].z]
            elbow = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_ELBOW.value].x,landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_ELBOW.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_ELBOW.value].z]
            wrist = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_WRIST.value].x,landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_WRIST.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_WRIST.value].z]
            
            # Calculate angle
            angle = Calc_Angle(shoulder, elbow, wrist)
            
            # Visualize angle
            cv2.putText(image, str(angle), 
                           tuple(np.multiply(elbow, [2560, 1440]).astype(int)), 
                           cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA
                                )
                       
        except:
            pass

        
        
        # Render detections
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.pose_landmarks, mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
                                mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,117,66), thickness=2, circle_radius=2), 
                                mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,66,230), thickness=2, circle_radius=2) 
                                 )               
        
        cv2.imshow('Mediapipe Feed', image)

        if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break








    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I tried this code I was able to capture my video feed and render the detections however the angle between the specified points did not show anywhere. It would be nice if any of you can help as I am fairly new to these technologies yet I need it for my project.

Comment: 3 3D points do not always form a single angle unless all 3 points lie on the same plane